# Check chrome web store user license from google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

Is it possible to use [client-side generated access token](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication) in a [server-side call](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#AccessTokenCredentials) to chromewebstore/v1.1/userlicenses/ to check user license? Both extension and app engine project registered on the same gmail account. I want to be able to tell if the user of my webapp has purchased my extension.

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
scope: [
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"].join(" "),
client_id: "xxxxx" 
}, () => gapi.client.myapi.check_payment().execute())
```

App engine code

```
import os
import urllib
import endpoints
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from protorpc import remote
from protorpc.message_types import VoidMessage

EXTENSION_ID = "xxxxx" # my extension id from Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard
API_KEY = "xxxxx"  # api key from Google APIs Console
CLIENT_ID = "xxxxx" # OAuth 2.0 client ID from Google APIs Console
SCOPES = [endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE]


@endpoints.api(name="myapi", version="v1", allowed_client_ids=[CLIENT_ID], scopes=SCOPES)
class MyApi(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(VoidMessage, VoidMessage)
    def check_payment(self, msg):
        user = endpoints.get_current_user()
        assert user is not None
        if "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" in os.environ:
            (tokentype, token) = os.environ["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"].split(" ")
            credentials = client.AccessTokenCredentials(token, 'my-user-agent/1.0')
            http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
            params = urllib.urlencode({"key": API_KEY})
            url = "https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/userlicenses/%s?%s" % (EXTENSION_ID, params)
            response = http.request(url)
```

Responds with 403 status: {"domain":"global","reason":"forbidden","message":"You don\'t have access to licensing data for App ID: xxxxx"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So yeah, there is no way for that to work, this kind of a request can only by authorized with a token minted by identity.getAuthToken.